# How do I set file permissions on a file when deploying an AWS Serverless Application with Maven

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, maven-shade-plugin, serverless-application-model

I want to deploy an AWS lambda function using the AWS Serverless Application Model with Maven. In the lambdas deployment zip file I want to include two external files (file1 and file2) that need to have executable permisions. (chmod 755 / -rwxr-xr-x). The files are both 64-bit ELFs

The files on my local machine have those permisions, however when built and deployed to AWS I can export and download the function from the online AWS lambda console to a ZIP and see that the deployed files now have the permisions -rw-r--r-- (chmod 644).

I have fixed this issue in Gradle before by quite simply doing something like `filesMatching('file1') { mode = 0755 }`

I am using:

- java11
- maven-shade-plugin 3.2.2

How do I achieve this in Maven? Here is the build portion of my pom.xml

```
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>files</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>file1</include>
                    <include>file2</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Use the maven-assembly-plugin ...?

Comment: Thanks for this. This is what I ended up doing. Please see my answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue, I ended up using maven-assembly-plugin as suggested by khmarbaise. My solution ended up looking like this:

This was the build section of my pom.xml

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>distribution.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then I added the file "distribution.xml" to the same directory as the POM.xml. Which looked like this.

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
<id>aws-lambda-package</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>files</directory>
        <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>file1</include>
            <include>file2</include>
        </includes>
        <fileMode>0755</fileMode>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

As a side effect of doing this I could no longer use the name of the function as the value for the codeURI in the template.yaml. So I needed to change it to the location of the zip file created when `maven clean install` is ran. Which in most peoples cases will be located: `<functionName>/target/<fileName>.zip`.